# At what age is a Ben Noach responsible to perform his "mitzvot"?

Tags: gentiles, age, noachide-laws

Jews are responsible for mitzvah performance at age 12 - girls and 13 for boys. (There is, as I understand, Rabbinical discussion regarding some specific mitzvot that they may be responsible when they reach *ben da'at* - "an age of understanding" - unclear if that's a specific age.)

But when does a Gentile become responsible for performing the 7 Noachide mitzvot?